# How to get node-fetch's data in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, node-fetch

I'm trying to make an application that sends JSON data to PHP server, and get responses from it. I'm using JavaScript [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) library for it.

Here is my sample code:

```
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");
    let data = JSON.stringify(something);

    fetch("https://example.com/api", {
        method: "post",
        body: data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(ret=>{
            console.log(ret);
        });
```

I'm trying to get this with $_POST in PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

But it returns empty array.

How can I get this on PHP, or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `$_POST` is only filled with values when receiving a request body with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` Content-Type header.

So you need to handle the JSON body like this:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents("php://input");
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, true);

var_dump($input);
```